# How to remove encoding attribute form xml?

Tags: xml, matlab

I want to create xml files to fit a specific format. So I want to remove the **encoding attribute** from the xml header tag. So instead of this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It would look this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
```

How can I tell **xmlwrite** function not to write encoding in the result?

Comment: I found a old post that may have answer for your question. See [Even More XML and MATLAB : Controlling XML Output](http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2012/02/20/even-more-xml-and-matlab-controlling-xml-output/). Mainly it says, you have to use Java to gain additional control.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. I did help.